# PrestoDB: worker nodes disconnects continuously (No worker nodes available)

Tags: presto

I am trying to setup a test PrestoDB cluster on 3 nodes (1 coordinator + 2 workers node) on Ubuntu 18.04 machines with 4GB RAM and 80GB HDD.

The **coordinator** properties are as follows:

- `node.properties`:

  ```
  node.environment=test
  node.id=2259f48c-bd6a-11e8-bbdd-1a4f1f5bd394
  node.data-dir=/opt/prestodata
  ```
- `jvm.properties`:

  ```
  -server
  -Xmx16G
  -XX:+UseG1GC
  -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
  -XX:+AggressiveOpts
  -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
  -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150M
  ```
- `config.properties`:

  ```
  coordinator=true
  node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
  http-server.http.port=8080
  query.max-memory=10GB
  query.max-memory-per-node=2GB
  discovery-server.enabled=true
  discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
  ```

The **worker-1** properties are as follows:

- `node.properties`:

  ```
  node.environment=test
  node.id=ca628078-bd69-11e8-807a-5e29ddb1dccc
  node.data-dir=/opt/prestodata
  ```
- `jvm.config`:

  ```
  -server
  -Xmx2G
  -XX:+UseG1GC
  -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
  -XX:+AggressiveOpts
  -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
  -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150M
  ```
- `config.properties`:

  ```
  coordinator=false
  http-server.http.port=8080
  query.max-memory=10GB
  query.max-memory-per-node=2GB
  discovery.uri=http://<coordinator_ip>:8080
  ```

Second worker properties are similar (with unique and valid UUID as well). On both workers, I (sometimes) see these logs:

```
Discovery server connect succeeded for refresh (collector/general)
Discovery server connect succeeded for refresh (presto/general)
```

On the coordinator node, I see that the worker nodes appear in **Active Workers** for about 1-2 seconds and disappear again, this cycle repeats 4-5 times everytime I restart worker nodes.

Ports are correctly whitelisted, workers & coordinator are reachable via `ping` from each other. Is this a problem with embedded discovery server or is the memory too less (4GB), what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I tried the following as well:

- Adding a separate discovery server instead of embedded server
- The latest version (0.211) instead of `0.198`
- Reversing coordinator and worker responsibilities
- Completely new installations with both versions

None of the above worked.

Comment: This issue being discussed on Github https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/11554

Comment: We have this exact same issue. the GitHub issue that is referenced here is not exactly the same problem. How did you overcome this issue?